# How much free will is need to gift Breath?

Tags: cosmere, warbreaker

In order to give away one's Breath, one must say the correct Command with the intent to give away the Breath. This is in keeping with Endowment's Intent, which is to give things. Brandon has also said that Breath would be difficult to steal with Hemalurgy. In that sense, Breath must be given away of one's own free will. However, it's a little unclear in the books how *much* free will is needed.

- Can you manipulate someone with emotional Allomancy into giving up their Breath?
- Would a more direct form of mind control work (through Hemalurgic spiking, voidspren, or what-have-you)?
- Can mundane forms of coercion such as torture or threats successfully persuade soemone to part with their Breath?

Comment: One needs to have the Intent to give Breath. There's no limitation to why they do have it, so any viable reason should work.

Comment: Vahr is tortured for his Breath, so torture and other types of coercion seem like they work. I'm not sure though about direct mind control.

Comment: Yes. No. Yes. 2 of those are manipulations and do not subvert free will.  One does.  *shrug* It's not that hard to find the line.

Comment: @Radhil - Different authors draw the line differently. It's highly subjective. There's multiple "sensible" and consistent ways to do it.

Comment: For instance, here in the real world, many wouldn't say a contract signed under torture was "signed of one's own free will."

Comment: @Radhil - And while we don't have emotional Allomancy, there are drugs that alter people's state of mind, such as alcohol. The law frequently does not recognize contracts or sexual intercourse by an intoxicated person as being of their own free will.

Comment: All of which is to say that there's no clear line. As Kai mentioned, seemingly torture absolutely works to get Breath, but I haven't heard compelling evidence on the rest (besides that it's obvious, but that's not so clear, and looks like your opinion; which is fine, but I think it's Sanderson's opinion that's going to influence how it works in the series).